# XAF Look up property displays correctly in listview but is null in detailview

Tags: entity-framework-6, nuget, xaf

I have the following business classes  ( simplified )

```
public class Customer {

  Customer()
  {
  }
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual Category {get;set;}
}

Public Class Category {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

If I paste them into a new XAF EF Winforms demo project they work correctly.

However in my development project the Category displays correctly in the listview but is null in the detail view.

Why?

[Nuget?]
The development project is using Nuget to install XAF.
I am currently working on making the demo project use Nuget to see if that causes the issue.

I don't think so, the demo project is still good after making it use Nuget.

[Presence of smallint in the database?]
This field is present in the table but not the model... investigating.

[LazyLoading?]
That would explain it but 
I can't see any setting turning this on

Comment: the table columns are varchar and not MaxLen... investigating whether that makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A public constructor is required
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q207865/unable-to-add-new-record-to-detail-view

```
public class Customer {

  public Customer()
  {
  }
  // etc
}
```